# Getting the area of a shape with abstrat classes and virtual functions

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance

Before I begin I must warn everyone that I only just started working with classes and inheritance in c++. Currently I'm working on a program that can get the area of multiple types of shapes. to do this the assignment required me to create an abstract base case with includes the virtual it also includes a getarea function so I can display the area in the main program. For derived classes for the various ways to get shapes here is an example of how one class would work

```
   class triangle : public BasicShapes{
     private:
            long base;
            long height;
            double areat;
     public:
          tringle(long b, long h){
             base=b;
             height=h;
             calcarea();
          }
          long getbase() const{
              return base;
          }
          long getheight() const{
              return height;
          }
          //this is the virtual function being used
          virtual void calcarea(){
              areat=.5(base*height);
              setarea(areat);
           }
   }
```

My problem is in the book all they wanted me to add in the abstract base class is a private double variable area, and a public function to get the area. I added most of the accessor function `setarea` in the base class so I could alter what was in the private variable in the basic shape class. I was wondering if there was a way to do this without using any type of accessor function or is my line of thinking the correct one. Also do people know how the main part of the program works I enter in the variables that would go into the object's constructor which would then show the calculations of the area along with the base and height or whatever shape I was trying to find the area for at the time.

Comment: Can you reproduce the exact wording of the assignment, or at least the part where they want you to define the variable? I think they might want you to calculate and set the area in the constructor, and not in any virtual function.

Comment: Basically in I'm trying to get the area for every shape in the abstract base class the only two things that are required are the private double variable area and the public function getarea along with the pure virtual function calcarea. in the derived classes I need a constructor that accepts the variables that I get from the main class and then calculate them in calcarea function.  the exception would be for the circle class where not only do I have to put the radius in put the center x and center y coordinates into the constructor.

Comment: also if anyone knows how the center x and y coordinates fit into getting the area of circle it would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to use all the variables.

Comment: The assignment doesn't make much sense, unless they expect you to cache the result of `calcarea` in the variable, which I doubt. This is why I have asked about the exact wording of the assignment.

Comment: Here's an abridged version of the assignment

Comment: the assignment wants me create an abstract base class that includes a private member variable area a public member function getarea, and a pure virtual calcarea that will be redefined in the derived classes. Then in the derived classes let's use triangle for example. In triangle it asks me to have two private member variables length and width ,and two public member functions getlength and getwidth. Then I redefine the calcarea so it can calculate the area. the same general idea applies to the other shapes.

Comment: In the driver  program the assignment wants me to get the input for the base and height, or whatever shape is  being used(like length, and width for a rectangle. then the assignment wants me to create an object with the variables I just entered in so it can assign them to the private variables in the constructor then the constructor calls the calcarea function which calculates the area. Then I display the info in the driver program.

Comment: I understand what calcarea should do, I don't quite understand what they want you to do with getarea and the variable, and also return it. One interpretation is to have getarea call calcarea and store the result in the variable. Try doing that first. Now think why it doesn't make much sense, and how to fix that.